# Netlogo modifying library Mouse Drag Multiple Example to a non wrapping world

Tags: mouse, selection, drag, netlogo, nowrap

Could anyone give some hints (or a full solution!) to how to convert the model library code example 'Mouse Drag Multiple Example' to a non wrapping world. My attempts destroy the selection rectangle (the sides of the rectangle pile up at the edge - because each part is treated separately). Similarly the selected turtles just pile up at the edge. Thank you.

Here's the main procedure from the model - it gives a runtime error on the second setxy when the side of the selection rectangle gets to the edge of the non-wrapping world:

```
to handle-drag
;; remember where the mouse pointer was located when
;; the user pressed the mouse button
let old-x mouse-xcor
let old-y mouse-ycor
if selected? old-x old-y [              ;; selected? is a reporter defined below
while [mouse-down?] [
  let new-x mouse-xcor
  let new-y mouse-ycor
  ;; we need to move both the selected turtles and the sides
  ;; of the selection rectangle by the same amount that the
  ;; mouse has moved.  we do this by subtracting the current
  ;; mouse coordinates from the previous mouse coordinates
  ;; and adding the results to the coordinates of the turtles
  ;; and sides.
  ask selected
    [ setxy xcor + new-x - old-x
            ycor + new-y - old-y ]
  ask sides
    [ setxy xcor + new-x - old-x
            ycor + new-y - old-y ]
  set old-x new-x
  set old-y new-y
  ;; update the view, otherwise the user can't see
  ;; what's going on
  display
]
]
end
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If the world doesn't wrap, where do you want the rectangles / agents to go if you drag them off the edge? Piling up at the edge seems a reasonable outcome.

Comment: The above code gives a runtime error when wrapping is switched off.  What is wanted is that the whole rectangle (and turtles inside) just gets stopped by the edge.  My attempts just have each part of the rectangle stopping at the edge, but now its just 4 lines at the edge!  Similarly, all the turtles move individually right up to the edge, losing their arrangement.  I am looking for some code that preserves the rectangle and insides when it hits the edge, without raising a runtime error.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is completely untested. It sounds like what you need is to pretest the potential position to make sure if doesn't go past the edge of the world and, if it does, reduce the amount of movement accordingly.

Try amending this section:

```
ask selected
[ setxy xcor + new-x - old-x
        ycor + new-y - old-y ]
ask sides
[ setxy xcor + new-x - old-x
        ycor + new-y - old-y ]
```

with:

```
let move-x new-x - old-x
let proposed-max-x max [x-cor] of selected + move-x
let proposed-min-x min [x-cor] of selected + move-x
if proposed-max-x > max-pxcor + 0.5 [let move-x max-pxcor + 0.5 - max [x-cor] of selected]
if proposed-min-x < min-pxcor - 0.5 [let move-x min-pxcor - 0.5 + min [x-cor] of selected]
ask selected
    [ setxy xcor + move-x ]
```

You will need to add in the sides (this only does selected) and do similar for y coordinates.

Comment: Thanks very much for your time.
I will follow your suggestion that any change in x- or y-coordinate is tested first before trying to move to it.  
Once the new position of the selection rectangle is approved, it should be possible to move the contents (the turtles) without testing?
Thank you again.
(Apologies for the delay responding - holiday!)